# How to publish to my own page's wall on Facebook

Tags: facebook

I just can't find out how to do this.

I'm building a website in scala (on google app-engine) and I made a facebook page for it and created a facebook application. All I want to do is to post to my own page's wall. I don't want to use java facebook api, 'cause I think it's way too much to do such a simple thing, but I really can't find a simple way to do so.

Is there a "low level" facebook api?? something simpler that works on posts and gets like twitter api for example?

Or any idea or alternative way to do so will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I am just checking back on this for follow up, have you figured this out and if not did you try the js method i posted with your pages access token as the token.  That is how i post via api to all my pages as the page itself.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, I found there is a REST-like api:

> This means that our Facebook method calls are made over the internet by sending HTTP GET or POST requests to the Facebook API REST server (http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php) . Nearly any computer language can be used to communicate over HTTP with the REST server.

Documentation here: http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/API

Answer (score 1):

Facebook has an API that you can use, but it isn't quite as straightforward as the Twitter API. It would be a bit of overkill to write in support, unless perhaps you are prototyping something for someone else to use.

For an individual case, you might be best served by using Posterous- if you setup a Posterous account linked to your Facebook Profile, emailing facebook@posterous.com with the sender set as yourself will likely be the easiest way to post content to your wall. With this, you can use any SMTP email-capable library that supports either HTML emails or attachments. An added bonus is that you can also cross-post to twitter and a number of other places from Posterous by altering the destination Posterous email.

Incidentally, Posterous also has an API too, but I don't remember off the top of my head if you can redirect where posted materials are sent through the API. I've only used it for image uploads, myself.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a strait forward out of the box wall feed example using Javascript SDK

SDK connection, just change the appId to your Applications own ID.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
    appId  : '135669679827333',
    status : true, // check login status
    cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml  : true, // parse XFBML
    //channelUrl : 'http://WWW.MYDOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // channel.html file
    oauth  : true // enable OAuth 2.0
        });
        if (window!=window.top) { 
        FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();
}

      };
      (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol +
          '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
      }());
</script>
```

---

Post Script, notice the to: parameter, change this to the page you wish to post to.  You can edit all other fields as needed.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    function feedthis() {
             FB.ui({ method: 'feed', 
            message: 'Testing Feed',
            caption: 'This is the Caption value.',
            name: 'Testing JS feed dialog on ShawnsSpace',
            link: 'http://shawnsspace.com?ref=link',
            to: '391793380398',
            description: 'Testing property links, and action links via Feed Dialog Javascript SDK',
            picture: 'https://shawnsspace.com/ShawnsSpace.toon.nocolor..png',
            properties: [{ text: 'Link Test 1', href: 'http://shawnsspace.com?ref=1'},
                            { text: 'Link Test 2', href: 'http://shawnsspace.com?ref=2'},
                            { text: 'Link Test 3', href: 'http://shawnsspace.com?ref=3'},
                            { text: 'Link Test 4', href: 'http://shawnsspace.com?ref=4'}
                            ],
            actions: [
            { name: 'Shawn', link: 'http://ShawnsSpace.com'}
            ]       
            });
            };

//]]>   
     </script>
<button onclick="feedthis();">Post to Wall</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two steps required to do this:

1. Create a custom Facebook App and add it as a tab to your page
2. Set this newly added tab as the default when a new user visits your page

Details:

**Create a custom Facebook App and add it as a tab to your page**

This step is tricky but manageable for an average HTML programmer. To illustrate it best, I will point to a great tutorial on this:
http://how-to-create-facebook-app.koliber.com/

**Set the tab as default**

1. As the admin, go to your page
2. In the upper-right corner click on "Edit Page"
3. Under the heading "Default Landing Tab", select the tab which
   contains the application you created earlier.